# JUnitParams with Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, mockito, junitparams

This could be a XY problem but I want to ask:

I am using [JUnitParams](https://github.com/Pragmatists/JUnitParams) to be able to run my test method 10 times with different objects. The problem is that the injections don't work (`@Mock` and `@InjectMocks`). I can use

```
PersonService personService = mock(PersonServiceImpl.class)
```

to mock the `PersonService` in the `@Test` method. But how do mock the "main" object that is annotated with `@InjectMock`? Maybe it is not possible and JUnitParams was only created for simple test cases that they exemplify with on their site.

If I can't use JUnitParams, what can I do instead? I have tried

```
@RunWith(value = Parameterized.class)
```

but that doesn't work either.. I think..

What I have:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class SkapaKundMasterDataTest {

    @InjectMocks
    private SkapaKundMasterData batch;

    @Mock
    private PersonService personService;

    @Mock
    private UtbetalningService utbetalningService;

    @Mock
    private Användare user;

    public Collection<PersonA[]> paramz() {

        List<PersonA[]> params = new ArrayList<>();
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(1111111111111L), new Personnummer(195001019999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1950, 1, 1), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(2222222222222L), new Personnummer(195102029999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1951, 2, 2), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null),});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(3333333333333L), new Personnummer(195203039999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1952, 3, 3), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(4444444444444L), new Personnummer(195304049999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1953, 4, 4), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(5555555555555L), new Personnummer(195405059999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1954, 5, 5), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(6666666666666L), new Personnummer(195506069999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1955, 6, 6), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(7777777777777L), new Personnummer(195607079999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1956, 7, 7), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(8888888888888L), new Personnummer(195708089999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1957, 8, 8), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(9999999999999L), new Personnummer(195809099999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1958, 9, 9), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});
        params.add(new PersonA[] {new PersonA(new PersonId(1234567891234L), new Personnummer(195910109999L), Datum.skapaDatum(1959, 10, 10), AllaArbetstagarFörEnPerson.utanArbetstagare(), null, null, null, null, null, false, null)});

        return params;
    }

    @Test
    @Parameters(method = "paramz")
    public void alltOk(PersonA dummy) throws BaseException {
        MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(SkapaKundMasterDataTest.class);
        //PersonService personService = mock(PersonServiceImpl.class); //this works
        when(personService.HämtaPersonAFörKundMasterdata(any(), any())).thenReturn(Optional.of(dummy));

        Properties p = new Properties();
        p.put("skummisar", "Ja");
        JobbParametrar params = JobbParametrar.skapa(p);

        batch.uppgift(dummy.getPersonId(), params, new KörningsId(0), any());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You cannot have two different runners simultaneously, but you can setup Mockito with a [Rule](https://github.com/junit-team/junit4/wiki/Rules). Just add the following to your test class while keeping the JUnitParamsRunner:

```
@Rule
public MockitoRule rule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned above, you cannot use two different runners simultaneously.

But there's another way to use both JUnitParamsRunner.class and MockitoJUnitRunner.class.

MockitoJUnitRunner.class is used to create mocked instances of classes annotated with @Mock. But the same think can be done with `MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this)`.

So, the whole test class would look something like this:

```
@RunWith(JUnitParamsRunner.class)
public class SkapaKundMasterDataTest {

   @InjectMocks
   private SkapaKundMasterData batch;

   @Mock
   private PersonService personService;

   @Mock
   private UtbetalningService utbetalningService;

   @Mock
   private Användare user;

   @Before
   public void setup() {
     MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
   }
   ...
   ...
}
```

By the way, constructor injection is preferred over field injection.